# (timezone aware) datetime in netcdf using python

Tags: python, datetime, netcdf

I'm trying to save a timeserie in a netcdf file. According to documentation I found, this can be done using the date2num method from the netCDF4 module. I can't get it working however (see example below):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from netCDF4 import num2date, date2num
import pytz

filename = 'test.nc'
root = Dataset(filename, 'w', format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
root.name = 'test'

# create dimension
root.createDimension('datetime', None)

# create variable
timeserie = root.createVariable('timeserie', 'f4', ('datetime',))
timeserie.units = 'days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' # reference: epoch
timeserie.calendar = 'gregorian'

# create testList
listDT = [dt.now(pytz.utc), dt(1970, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0, 0, pytz.utc)]
print date2num(listDT, units=timeserie.units, calendar=timeserie.calendar)

root.close()
```

The error it gives me:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
>     print date2num(listDT, units=timeserie.units, calendar=timeserie.calendar)
>   File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 5128, in netCDF4._netCDF4.date2num (netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:60367)
> TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
> ```

How would I save datetime data (preferably timezone aware) to netcdf using python?

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The [date2num() doc](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.date2num) says that the datetime object must be UTC. A number cannot be timezone aware,unless it is UTC. Would cause great problems with standard/daylight time transitions.

Try

```
listDT = [dt.now(), dt(1970, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0, 0)]
print date2num(listDT, units=timeserie.units, calendar=timeserie.calendar)
```

To demonstrate that it is timezone aware, try Eastern offset as units.

```
print date2num(listDT, units='days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00-04:00', calendar=timeserie.calendar)
```